# How to upgrade my system’s WebGL from v1.0 to v2.0

Tags: macos, webgl

- Apple Mac Pro (early 2009) 4,1->5,1
- macOS 10.14.2
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 120 512 M

I have been trying to run the [Magenta Studio (Ableton Live Plugin)](https://magenta.tensorflow.org/studio/ableton-live) without success. In the course of discussions with the developers, we established that the fact that my WebGL was v1.0 meant that the code wouldn't run properly because it has a dependency on v2.0.

They have promised to put out a release that gets around this problem, but in the meantime, it occurred to me that maybe I could upgrade the WebGL from 1.0 to 2.0.

So is it possible to upgrade WebGL from 1.0 to 2.0? Or do I have to upgrade my graphics drivers to make this possible?

Comment: How did you even get Mojave running on a Mac with no Metal-capable GPU? https://support.apple.com/HT208898 You ought to be able to run WebGL 2 [at least in a browser, Safari has it as a beta feature - WebGL2 isn't a finalised standard yet.] but idk how it relates to a standalone app.

Comment: @Tetsujin There is a patcher to the installer that allows macOS Mojave to be installed on unsupported systems. That said, I did this on a Mac Pro 2010 and wow… The UX was unusable due to the unsupported graphics card.

Comment: @JakeGould - I'd imagine so - though it's fine on a fully 'uprated' 09 with Metal GPU, btw; I was leading towards what Mokubai had a more solid answer to.

Comment: @Tetsujin I used the patch from dosdude1.com/mojave. Even though my Mac is ancient, it has 32GB of RAM on board and runs Mojave very sweetly.

Comment: You wouldn't need the patcher if you upgraded the GPU - & you'd also probably get your WebGL along with it.

Comment: Safari does indeed have an option for WebGL 2.0 in the Developers Menu, but as you note, it doesn't help the standalone app.

Comment: @Tetsujin funds are severely limited at the moment, so a hardware upgrade isn't really on the cards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a graphics card upgrade is needed.

The various [WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) versions are based on [OpenGL ES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES) which in turn are roughly equivalent to versions of OpenGL.

Per the WebGL Wikipedia article **Support** section:

> WebGL is widely supported in modern browsers. However its availability is dependent on other factors like the GPU supporting it.

Looking through those pages give the following vague chart.

```
WebGL Version | OpenGL ES | OpenGl
WebGL 1.0     | ES 2.0    | ~2.0 - 3.1
WebGL 2.0     | ES 3.0    | > 4.3
```

Your graphics card is a [GT 120](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_100_series?wprov=sfla1) which is only capable of OpenGL version 3.3.

For WebGL 2.0 you will need an OpenGL version greater than 4.3. Anything newer than an Nvidia 4xx series card seems to fit the bill.  I cannot recommend a specific card because I have no experience of Macs and what will work with them or what power you have available.